# Which is more efficient call --> goto &fun($val) or fun($val) in perl ?

Tags: perl, goto

Which is more efficient statement --> goto &fun($val) or fun($val) in perl ? 
When to use which statement for better performance ?
Please let me know the answer !

Comment: They don't do the same thing, although this seems like premature optimization at best anyway.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? If you don't know when to use `goto`, you almost certainly don't ever want to use it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this is the wrong question to ask.

The form `fun($val)` is the standard way to call another subroutine in perl.

The form `goto &func` is normally used to transfer control to another sub while removing the current stack frame. In addition, `@_` is passed unaltered to the called routine.

The removal of the stack frame means that `caller()` will not see it, so that the `&func` will think that  t was called by the caller of the routine which performed the `goto`. It also means that performing a backtrace in the debugger will not reveal the routine performing the `goto`.

If you want to preserve the calling stack frame but pass control to a function with the current setting of `@_`, then use `return &func`.

The form `goto &func($val)` is parsed as:

```
my $label = &func($val);
goto $label;
```

This will likely give a `Can't find label ...` error.

Examples:

```
sub func {
  my $x = shift;
  print "x = $x\n";
  my ($package, $file, $line) = caller();
  print "caller file: $file, line: $line\n";
}

sub foo {
  goto &func("from goto bar");
}

sub baz {
  return &func;
}

sub quux {
   goto &func;
}

baz("from baz");
quux("from quux");
foo("from foo");
```

Answer (score 3):

Surprise of my life.  The no-goto version seems to be faster.  So little reason to use anything else than normal function calls, apart from deep recursion.

```
             Rate with_goto   no_goto
with_goto 56818/s        --      -21%
no_goto   71942/s       27%        --
```

Tested with this:

```
use Benchmark ':all';

sub with_goto { $_[0]-- and goto &with_goto }
sub   no_goto { $_[0]-- and      &  no_goto }

cmpthese( 100000, {
  with_goto => '$_=98; with_goto($_)',
    no_goto => '$_=98;   no_goto($_)',
});
```

(still baffled)

Comment: It's not surprising that it takes longer, since it has to tear down the stack in an unusual manner. How much longer? (1/56818 - 1/71942) / 98 = 0.000,0000,377; or 0.4ns. Seriously, why are we talking about speed?

Comment: In my naive mind, replacing the top frame should take about as long as pushing (amortized), whereas returning is constant time vs linear.  Hence my surprise.

Answer (score 2):

*Always* use `fun($val)`.  It's more readable and any performance difference will be small enough that, if it matters to you, then you shouldn't be using Perl in the first place.  Not to mention that the `goto` version probably doesn't do what you intend anyhow - they are *not* synonymous.

Unless you've already profiled your code to determine that subroutine dispatching is taking up a significant portion of your CPU cycles (highly unlikely that it would be!) *and* you've benchmarked code to compare the two ways of doing it to ensure that, in your particular case, there is enough of a difference for it to matter (even less likely!), this is a very, very premature optimization.  If you're having performance problems, look at your algorithms instead of worrying about such a tiny, tiny microoptimization.